# Reading xml file using QDomDocument just get the first line

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I generate a xml file using QXmlStreamWriter. The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pedestrianinfo>
    <pedestrian uuid="2112e2ed-fc9b-41e8-bbcb-b44ad78bde11">
        <module>11.1208</module>
        <direction>4</direction>
        <row>5</row>
        <column>71</column>
    </pedestrian>
    <pedestrian uuid="1aabb9c1-4aa7-4f47-9542-36d2dfaa26e4">
        <module>1.48032</module>
        <direction>4</direction>
        <row>67</row>
        <column>31</column>
    </pedestrian>

...

</pedestrianinfo>
```

Then I try to read the content by QDomDocument. My code looks like this:

```
xmlReader *xp = new xmlReader(QString("D:\\0T.xml"));
    if(xp->openFile()) {
        if(xp->isGetRootIndex()) {
            xp->parseRootIndexElement();
        }
        else
            cout<<"Unable to get root index."<<endl;
    }
```

Here is isGetRootIndex():

```
bool xmlReader::isGetRootIndex()
{
    doc.setContent(&file,false);
    root = doc.documentElement();
    if(root.tagName() == getRootIndex()) //rootIndex=="pedestrianinfo"
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is parseRootIndexElement():

```
void xmlReader::parseRootIndexElement()
{
    QDomNode child = root.firstChild();
    while(!child.isNull()) {
        if(child.toElement().tagName() == getTagNameP())  //"childTagName=="pedestrian"
            parseEntryElement(child.toElement());
        qDebug()<<"module="<<module<<" direction="<<direction<<" row="<<row<<" column="<<column;
        child = child.nextSibling();
    }
}
```

parseEntryElement(const QDomElement &element) is a function to get the infomation in each tag and save them into variables such as module.
However, each time I run my code, only the first child of xml file could be qDebug*ed*. It seems that after executing child.nextSibling(), child becomes null. Why does it not get the next pedestrian info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks correct to me based on what I see in the documentation. Perhaps parseEntryElement is advancing the iterator unexpectedly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Today I found a terrible mistake I've made. The program read the 'old' xml file instead of the correct one. Oops. The code works for me now.